# Get user ID in Azure Pipelines

Tags: azure-devops, azure-active-directory, azure-pipelines

Is it possible to access the user ID and use it in an Azure pipelines yaml file? I have looked at the built in variables and it does not seem as though this is included there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems as though the this functionality can be provided by the Build.QueuedById variable (obviously only if the build was triggered manually by someone).

Check out the learn.microsoft link here: [How are the identity variables set?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#identity_values)

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to run this task in the pipeline:

```
- task: NuGetAuthenticate@1
  inputs:
    nuGetServiceConnections:
```

***service connection intentionally left blank to auth against current ADO environment***

Which gives something similar to this in the pipeline output:

```
Setting up the credential provider to use the identity 'Project Collection Build Service (**yourOrg**)' for feeds in your organization/collection starting with:
  https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/**yourOrg**/
  https://**yourOrg**.pkgs.visualstudio.com/
```